# Is this user spamming?

Tags: discussion

I'm very new here so I may be wildly off mark, but after reading the FAQ again I'm not sure if this is kosher.

I saw 3 simultaneous questions from one user here 1 hour ago and so I decided to have a look as two were definitely not up to the normal standards (I dont have rights to vote yet so I cant do much about it or flag them).

Questions here: [What's the reason behind collision-boxes?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32881/whats-the-reason-behind-collision-boxes), [Writing a Massive Multiplayer Onlinegame by Own](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32882/writing-a-massive-multiplayer-onlinegame-by-own) [How to handle a Block World like Minecraft](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/how-to-handle-a-block-world-like-minecraft)

Wondering how he got so much rep while asking these kinds of questions I looked at the profile and it seems the user posts alot of questions of SO which are answered and the answers accepted allowing the user's rep to reach that point where it crosses sites.

So I guess my question is, is constructive question spamming for rep gain considered spam or do we have a http://xkcd.com/810/ on our hands here?

[Obviously its just as likely as it a new user who hasn't read the FAQ and I'm being very paranoid!]

Comment: I think it's just a case of I-want-to-make-an-awesome-minecraft-MMO-itis and not intentional spamming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fail to see the spamming. He was asking several questions in a short period of time, but some people are curious :)

If you have at least 200 rep on any stackexchange account and associate that account with another one, then you get 100 reputation as a starting bonus. Nothing fishy here.

Also some of his questions got downvoted so heavily, I really doubt he was asking this for the reputation.

Comment: Cheers, good to know! (sorry for the massive lag, I've been off on holiday)